# Group by two properties as one in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class

```
public class Booking
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public BookingType Type { get; set; }
    public BookingStatus Status { get; set; }
    public InvoiceFreq { get; set; }
    public InvoiceLevel { get; set; }
}
```

That I'd need to group them by all properties in Linq so that the last two properties form one new field in the grouped result. 
Like this:

```
        Group   Type    Status      InvoiceType          
        -------------------------------------------
        Group1  Online  New         Daily-Single
        Group2  Phone   Accepted    Daily-Single
        Group3  Store   Accepted    Weekly-Single
        Group3  Store   Accepted    Weekly-Bulk
```

Here the InvoiceFreq will be Daily / Weekly and the InvoiceLevel = Single or Bulk.

The query I have so far is this:

```
        var query = from b in Bookings
                        group b by new
                        {
                            b.Group, 
                            b.Type, 
                            b.Status,
                            b.InvoicingFrequency,
                            b.InvoicingLevel
                        } into bookingGroup
                        select new BookingSummaryLine()
                        {
                            Group = bookingGroup.Key.UserGroup,
                            Type = bookingGroup.Key.UserGroup,
                            Status = bookingGroup.Key.FinancialStatus,
                            InvType = String.Format({0}-{1},bookingGroup.Key.InvoicingFrequency, bookingGroup.Key.InvoicingLevel
                        };
```

This of course does not give the desired result as the two properties are in the anonymous type separately.

Is there any way to achieve this in Linq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
var query = from b in Bookings
    group b by new
    {
        b.Group, 
        b.Type, 
        b.Status,
        InvType = String.Format({0}-{1},b.InvoicingFrequency, b.InvoicingLevel)
    } into bookingGroup
    select new BookingSummaryLine()
    {
        Group = bookingGroup.Key.UserGroup,
        Type = bookingGroup.Key.UserGroup,
        Status = bookingGroup.Key.FinancialStatus,
        InvType = bookingGroup.Key.InvType
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as sure about the syntax for linq but for lambda I would use this. Basically use distinct if your trying to group on all columns like that.

```
Context.Booking.Distinct().Select(z=> new BookingSummaryLine { Group = z.Group, Type =        z.Type, Status = z.Status, InvType = (z.InvoiceFrequency + "-" + z.InvoiceLevel });
```